# css/jquery: Text Fade-In - This should work in IE8, can anyone tell me why it doesn't?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, fade

So, yeah IE8 is terrible, but I need this to be compatable. It works fine in Firefox and I switched from pure CSS to CSS/jQuery so that it should work with IE8.

This is the CSS:

```css
#test p {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I think it's the CSS Opacity that IE8 doesn't like.

Edit: Solved, answer is below.

Comment: IE8 and earlier doesn't support opacity, use something like this ->   filter:Alpha(opacity=50).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've solved this with a bit more looking and decided to add the answer.

The CSS needed to be changed to:

```
#test p {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Since IE8 doesn't support Opacity, it needed the:

filter: alpha(opacity=0);

This then "breaks" the text, causes the edges to become jagged/blurry and very ugly looking. To fix this a background needed to be added:

background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;

Both amendments are in the code above and this now works fine. I may have been a bit premature with this question, however the solution can now be found in one place with this answer!

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that for ie8 you better use this code:

```
filter: alpha(opacity=100)
```

than the opacity.
note the number changes from 0 to 100 not 0 to 1 like opacity

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same effect with something like this. Works fine in all browsers

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0"/>
<title>HTML5 Template</title>
<style type="text/css">
#test p {
    display:none;
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div>
<script>
$("#test p").delay(1000).fadeIn("slow");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```